# Finding the average of lines in data file using list subscripts

Tags: python, list, file, text-files

The program is supposed to read the individual lines of the .txt file and find the average of each individual's test scores. My .txt file in Notepad looks like this...

```
    John Smith 5 9 8 10 7
    Mary Brown 3 10 8 4 2
    Bob Black  7 10 9 10 8
```

And the final program after importing the data file should look like this...

```
    Filename? file1.txt     ## file1.txt = the name of the data file the user input
    John Smith 7.8
    Mary Brown 5.4
    Bob Black 8.8

    Average over all students = 7.333333333333333
```

This is my Python code...

```
    def main():

        filename = input("Filename? ")
        filename = filename + ".txt"

        with open(filename,"r") as file:
            for lines in file:
            wholefile = lines.strip()
            print(wholefile)

        print("")

        average = 7.333333333333333      ## This is simply a placeholder!
        print("Average over all students =", average

    main()
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing... How do I accomplish this task using list subscripts and an if statement?

Comment: OK, Seems this is your homework. So do you have any idea for the rest of your code? Why did you put this `print(wholefile)` there?

Answer (score 6):

Some pointers:

```
>>> s = "John Smith 5 9 8 10 7"
>>> l = s.split()
>>> l
['John', 'Smith', '5', '9', '8', '10', '7']
>>> grades = [int(item) for item in l if item.isdigit()]
>>> grades
[5, 9, 8, 10, 7]
>>> grades = []     # or, if you haven't done list comprehensions yet:
>>> for item in l:
...     if item.isdigit():
...         grades.append(int(item))
...
>>> grades
[5, 9, 8, 10, 7]
>>> sum(grades)/len(grades)
7.8
```